# Need php page to echo the url of a current chrome tab via chrome extension post method

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension clickable icon that works in that it will call and display the target php page.  However, When clicked, I want to retrieve the full url of the current browser tab and post it to a php page.  That php page needs to simply echo the url sent to it.  Seems easy enough and there are several closely related SO pages that discuss similar issues, from which I developed the below code.  At present, the php page is called, but I cannot get it to echo the url.  All I get is `array(0) { }`.  I've tried a number of code modifications from the fine SO Q&A's, but at this point I'm uncertain as to where the issue is... Any solution is acceptable, I'm not limited or bound to the methods being attempted here.

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "A chrome extension plugin",
  "description": "Some descriptive text.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "anIcon.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
   "activeTab"
   ]
}
```

popup.html

```
<!doctype html5>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Text</title>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>More Text</h1>
        <button id="checkPage">Enlighten me!</button>
      </body>
    </html>
```

popup.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var checkPageButton = document.getElementById('checkPage');
    checkPageButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tab){
            doc = document;
            var form = doc.createElement('form');
            form.action = 'http://myGreatSite.com/ABC.php';
            form.method = 'post';
            var input = doc.createElement('input');
            input.type = 'hidden';
            input.name = 'url';
            input.value = tab[0].url;
            form.appendChild(input);
            doc.body.appendChild(form);
            form.submit();
        });
    }, false);
}, false);
```

myGreatSite/ABC.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML5>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Give me the calling URL</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Here's the calling URL</h1>
<?php
var_dump($_REQUEST);
var_dump($_POST);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bahhhh! After many hours of thrashing about, turns out, myGreatSite.com has an SSL cert installed, and even though there is an .htaccess file that allows it to be called with http and https, for our puposes here, it must be called like the below. The trailing slash is a good idea as well. I am uncertain as to why this is...

```
form.action = 'https://myGreatSite.com/ABC.php/';
```